# Get month from datefield

Tags: angularjs, date, django-rest-framework

I using Django-rest and I want to get month form Datefield in AngularJS.

My code is `date = '2014-2-30'` and I get month: `var x = (new Date (Date.parse (date).getMonth()`.

But `x = 1` and value of `year = 114`.

I read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date but I can't do it. Would you give me example?

Comment: is your datefiled is a javascript object or just a date string ?

Comment: Can you paste some relevant code to a plunkr?

Comment: My datefield is model DateField in django's library

Comment: My code is: date = '2014-2-30'; and i get month: var x = (new Date(Date.parse("1-5-2012"))).getMonth(). But my value's x = 1 and value of year = 114 don't = 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST Framework should pass dates back to Angular in ISO 8601 format (`yyyy-MM-dd`), so there shouldn't be an issue parsing it on Angular's side.

```
{{ obj.date | date:"MMMM" }}
```

`MMMM` is the Angular date code for the full month (`January-December`). You can find other Angular date codes [in the `date` filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).